Questions tagged with a synonym of a tag and closed by a user with a gold badge for the master tag incorrectly show the synonym in the close notice
The situation is very likely related to Questions migrated to localized meta sites get the [discussion] tag in English even if it's synonymized to the localized tag equivalent
But in this case migrated question (with incorrect tag [discussion] instead of [обсуждение] at the time of closing) is closed by dup-hammer:



The tag that mentioned as gold [discussion] is not the primary tag on ruSO.meta, it's a synonym for [обсуждение] (Russian word used for "discussion").
The primary tag [обсуждение] must be used instead there. That's how it should look:




@W.O. there are not cross-site synonyms. There is only ruSO.meta synonym. The problem lays somewhere around [discussion] tag, that's default on most meta sites (English-based), but may differ on others.

Ah, I misunderstood. It raises an issue that I'll have a think about though, to do with other migrations.
